# How to make child fill all avaliable height of parent in flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a two divs, Parent and Child.

And I need to make Child fill all available height of Parent.

But for some reason I have this padding at the bottom.

I can remove it only when I use height `105%` for Child

But this is obviously not the best solution.

I tried to use `align-items: stretch`, but it didn't do anything.

```html
<div 
  style={{
    width: 100%;
  height: 92%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  }}
>
  <div
    style={{
      height: '100%',
      backgroundColor:'red',
    }}
  >
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: `flex: basis: 100%;` on child.

Comment: I've turned your posted code (though you didn't add any colours) into a snippet, so people can easily reproduce the problem. I made the assumption that the inline CSS would just be converted to CSS in the style attribute, so if that's incorrect please correct the snippet to ensure it works as you describe.

Comment: does it change something when you remove the simple quote `'` from 100% and red ? Because I do the same and the child took 100% from parent. On your screen, it looks like the child get something like `height: inherit` so only 92% from parent.

Comment: @zerbene When i remove 100% from child it doesnt  do anything.
But when i use 105% for child it gets larger. So it looks like it uses 100% already initially.
Although it don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `flex-basis: 100%;` on the flex item.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

body>div:first-child {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

div>div {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>foo</div>
</div>
```

You can see from the second example below it works despite having a static or dynamic sized parent.

```css
body>div:first-child {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

div>div {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>foo</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried it also.
And it overflows parent

Comment: @KarinaShulan Then it is obvious something is missing from your example in the question. I provided two solutions demonstrating `flex-basis` and neither overflow the parent. Please post a [example].

Comment: Sorry @Kameron that was my browser which showed old version of page after refresh.
It works great, thank you so so much.

Answer (score 0):

The width or height of the parent container needs to be specific/absolute. So intead of setting the height of the parent to 92%, you can try 92vh.

```html
<div 
      style={{
        width: 100%;
        height: 92vh;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        box-sizing: content-box;
      }}
    >
      <div
        style={{
          height: '100%',
          backgroundColor:'red',
        }}
      >
      abc
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried it, but it overflows parent now.

Comment: Can you send your code? Maybe you are having margin somewhere or padding in the child div. If that is the case you can set the box-sizing of the child to border-box

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few basics already laid out. I reformatted it a bit too for readability. You had background-color as backgroundColor, as well as 100% to '100%'.

If you take this as a basis, just change the width and height of it to 100% and you should have no problem. The larger change was setting the position, and ensuring that you'r setting a height and width.

```
<body style="position: absolute; padding: 0; margin: 0; width: 100vw; height: 100vh; background-color: aquamarine; display: flex; justify-content: center;">

 <div style="
    position: relative;
    width: 70%; 
    height: 70%;  
    align-self: center;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    border: 2px solid grey;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;">
    <div style = "
        position:relative;
        align-self: center;
        height: 80%; 
        width: 80%;
        background-color: red;">
    </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

I added a few styles to the body as well to help with understanding what's happening.